# Ajax PUT call resulting in illegal invocation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, put

I'm trying to modify an existing xml document that i stored from an earlier ajax call into a global variable named "XML".

Now, im trying to change a title in the xml document to be whatever the user wants to change it to. For some reason i keep getting "uncaught type error: Illegal invocation" after my ajax put call, however my success function executes. My code is below:

```
$("#saveButton").click(function(event) {

    var url = links[$("#nameInput").val()]; //the url of the xml file to be modified

    changeXML(XML); //XML is global variable where i stored the xml file from 'GET' call earlier

    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: XML,
            type: 'PUT',
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: window.location.reload()
        });
});
function changeXML(xml){

    var title = $("#titleInput").val();//obtains user input for title change

    $(xml).find('title').first().text(title);//changes title to what user entered


    }
```

The global variable xml file that i saved is actually being modified, however upon reloading the window, i find that the xml file that the changes are supposed to be put into isnt changing, just the local variable one.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reloading the page before the ajax call is made, you have to pass a function to the success parameter, not call one.
`window.location.reload()` is called before the ajax request is made, wrap it in a function add set that as the success callback.
Also It looks like XML is a jQuery object, you have to convert it to an xml string.

```
var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
var data = oSerializer.serializeToString(XML);
$.ajax({
        ...
        contentType: 'text/xml', //set the content type not the data type
        data: data,
        success: function(){
            window.location.reload();
        }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. Well you were right about it reloading the page before making the ajax request, this made me believe (falsely) that the ajax request was successful. However, after making the change you suggested, i realize the call isn't successful. The success function never executes and I'm still getting "uncaught type error: Illegal invocation".

Comment: So that definitely took me a step in the right direction. I'm almost there! Unfortunately however now I'm getting an error:


PUT"excluded-link-to-my-webpage" 405 (Method Not Allowed)jquery.min.js:4 n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.sendjquery.min.js:4 n.extend.ajaxjs.js:158 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:3 n.event.dispatchjquery.min.js:3 n.event.add.r.handle


I've checked the url and its definitely fine. Im using a live website that I have in order to test this. Researched this error and i read that people encountering it had to enable cors, whatever that is. Guess i need to do that

Comment: That error means that you cant make `PUT` requests, make sure you configure your server to accept them.